# Django manipulate / modify date in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Is it possible to make an input that changes the date.today for the whole template ?

my template

```
{% for Ansicht in Ansicht.lehrertabelle_set.all  %} 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row"></th>
    <td>{{Ansicht.Pflichtstunden_normal}}</td>
    <td>{{Ansicht.Status_normal}}</td>
    {% if Ansicht.Prognose_FK %} 
    <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Status}}</td>
    <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Stunden}}</td>
    {% else %}
    <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Status_2}}</td>
    <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Stunden_2}}</td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

the filter then would show
those

```
    <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Status_2}}</td>
    <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Stunden_2}}</td>
```

instead of the first ones when the date is modified, I tried to use javascript but I guess it dont work bc of python objects

my model is

```
class PrognoseTabelle(models.Model):
    Benutzer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    Lehrer_FK = models.ForeignKey('LehrerTabelle', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='LehrerNName', null=True, blank=True)
    #######Status 1######
    von_Datum = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Stunden = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    bis_Datum = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #######Status 2######
    von_Datum_2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Status_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    Stunden_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    bis_Datum_2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #######Status 3######
```

Comment: How does this code relate to date.today?

Comment: edited my question. It is connected to another model, I cant post everything cuz to much but it has 7 entries each of them has their own date and I need to have a filter in the template to filter those by date so that it shows something within the input given date

Comment: I only need a variable from the input that a compare in the if tag like that {% if Ansicht.Prognose_FK.von_Datum <= 'variable' %} show the first Prognoise_FK and so on

Comment: Is it ok, if the user needs to press a button after inputting the date?

Comment: yes yes yes yes button form whatever I take everythong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to influence the rendered HTML from only server-side code, after it has been rendered and displayed by the user. If I understand you correctly, your intended user interaction with this view/menu looks kind of like this:

1. User action: The user opens the menu.
2. Program action: Among other things, a date-input is displayed.
3. User action: The user inputs a date using the date-input.
4. Program action: The displayed content changes.

Given, that you cannot influence the rendered HTML with only server-side code in step 4., you have two possibilities to achieve this:

1. display new rendered HTML
2. use client-side code (for example JavaScript)

I'm going to explain the first possibility here:

It's probably the easiest to use a django form to render the input.
forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from django.utils.timezone import localdate

class PrognoseFilterForm(forms.Form):
    """Form for filtering the Prognose table."""
    datum = forms.DateField()
```

somewhere in views.py:

```py
def prognose_tabelle_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = PrognoseFilterForm(request.GET, initial={'date': timezone.localdate()})
    datum = timezone.localdate()
    if form.is_bound() and form.is_valid():
        datum = form.cleaned_data['datum']        

    prognose_query = Ansicht.lehrertabelle_set.all()
    prognoseansichten_bis_einschliesslich_datum = prognose_query.filter(
        Prognose_FK__von_Datum__lte=datum
    )
    prognoseansichten_ab_datum = prognose_query.filter(
        Prognose_FK__von_Datum__gt=datum
    )
    
    return render(
        request,
        'your_app/prognose_tabelle.html',
        context={
            'filter_form': form,
            'prognosen_bis_datum': prognoseansichten_bis_einschliesslich_datum,
            'prognosen_ab_datum': prognoseansichten_ab_datum,
        }
    )
```

prognose_tabelle.html:

```html
<form action="{% url '<name of the view according to urls.py>' %}" method="get">
  {{ filter_form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit">Filtern</input>
</form>
<table>
  <tbody>
    {% for Ansicht in prognosen_bis_datum %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Pflichtstunden_normal}}</td>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Status_normal}}</td>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Status}}</td>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Stunden}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for Ansicht in prognosen_ab_datum %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Pflichtstunden_normal}}</td>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Status_normal}}</td>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Status_2}}</td>
        <td>{{Ansicht.Prognose_FK.Stunden_2}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When a user clicks the button labelled with "Filtern", the form data is sent to the view via an HTTP-Get-Request in its GET-Parameters. The server then responds with a new HTML page, which the browser then displays to the user.

Comment: Yeeesss this is what I need, doenst display the filter form though can we maybe chat ?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. If you still need help, I can take a look at your code, if you want.

Comment: that would be amazing, I just need someone to talk to. How can I write u private ?